# master detail with combobox and a grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use combobox and grid from Telerik KendoUI for PHP and I am trying to make master detail relation so when the current selected item change in the combobox the grid update its current data.

Here is the combobox code:

```
$comboBox = new \Kendo\UI\ComboBox('combobox');

$comboBox->dataTextField('text')
         ->dataValueField('value')
         ->dataSource(array(
            array('text' => 'Item 1', 'value' => '1'),
            array('text' => 'Item 2', 'value' => '2'),
            array('text' => 'Item 3', 'value' => '3')
         ))
         ->change('onChange');
?>
<div class="demo-section">
    <h3 class="title">ComboBox
    </h3>
<?php
echo $comboBox->render();
?>
</div>

<script>
function onChange() {

}
</script>
```

The grid used is just standard one that get data from PHP file that return the data in json format.

Should I use the onChange() event to update the grid ? any example ? you dont have to use my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the onChange approach is a good idea. If you have your JSON data from the file in some variable you can filter that data down in the event of a change to your combobox and manually set the data on the details grid. Something like:

```
function onChange(e){

    var selectedComboBoxValue = this.value();

    var gridData = $.grep(myJSONdata, function(item){
        // Filter down your JSON down using jQuery's grep method where myJSONdata is representing the variable holing your JSON array from the php file.
        // Change this equality check to use whatever property is appropriate.
        return item.value == selectedComboBoxValue;
    });

    // Grab a reference to the grid. Modify the selector as needed.
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    // Pass in your filtered data to refresh the grid.
    grid.dataSource.data(gridData);
}
```